# How to keep hover-generated icon positioned over image after scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a simple chrome extension to place a download button over any image that you hover your mouse over. The problem is the positioning of this icon is based on the location of the hovered image at the time of mouseover, so if you scroll and your cursor stays hovered on the image as the scroll happens, the icon stays visible but does not follow the scroll because it's position is just static until you stop hovering and it goes away. I made a picture to more easily explain. I'm trying to have the icon follow the corresponding image if you scroll while keeping your cursor hovered.

[Hover before and after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sflfT.jpg)

The problem is that I cannot just give it position: absolute because ideally I can use this on any website and I cannot always account for the parent div attributes. So I position based on the location on the page at the time hover.

```
    let left= img.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().left+10,
         top= img.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().top+10;
    $('body').prepend(`
            <img id="ext-emp-download" src="${chrome.runtime.getURL("img/down.png")}" style="width:45px !important;height:45px !important;position:fixed;z-index:123456789;border-radius:20px;margin-top:${top}px;left:${left}px">`)
```

any suggestions on what I can add to this to make it function better or  have the icon follow the image with the scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using *margin-top*, use *top* instead **and** use **position:absolute** instead of **fixed**, also since it seems you are already using **jQuery** (?), use **jQuery**:s *offset*-method to calculate the placement rather than *getBoundingClientRect*:

```
let left = img.offset().left + 10, top = img.offset().top + 10;
  $('body').prepend(`
  <img id="ext-emp-download" src="${chrome.runtime.getURL("img/down.png")}" style="width:45px !important;height:45px !important;position:absolute;z-index:123456789;border-radius:20px;top:${top}px;left:${left}px">`)
```

Comment: holy cow this worked perfectly, thank you so much. my code was like cobbled together by random bits of similar but not identical solutions so I knew it couldn't have been ideal.

I thought position: absolute was out of the question because I cannot control the attributes of the parent divs always, but clearly I don't know the limitations very well.

Thank you again

Comment: Glad it worked, Mike! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good solution for this especially if you want to account for all possible scenarios of the parent element.

However, instead of appending your element to the `body` element, you can choose to append to the [`.scrollParent()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/scrollParent/) of the `img` tag instead. This makes sure the position of it is dependent on the element that is scrolling. In addition, `position: fixed` is probably not what you want given that once the user scroll, you have to manually update its position.

An alternative approach is you can make use of context menu instead: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/, this allow user to right-click and select your extension for "Download" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute; and make parent position: relative; then icon will folow parent.